# Dataframe - Pandas - What is the difference between drop and loc in size of the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a dataframe and it is needed to remove unwanted values from it. Only price greater than 10 should be kept in the dataframe and below this should be removed.

There are two ways to do it:

```
df = df.loc[df.price > 10]
```

or

```
df = df.drop(df[df['price'] < 10].index)
```

What is the difference between these two?

And which one is faster?

And also free the space used by dataframe in memory?

Thank you.

Comment: which one is faster, you can test by `timeit`

Comment: I would guess the first one is faster.

Comment: Quick note: to make them comparable you need to add = to the second method, i.e.: df = df.drop(df[df['price'] <= 10].index)